# Localize iOS 14 dynamic widget configuration

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios14, widgetkit

I am trying to load different configuration for the widgets depending on the app language, but when I use something like:

```
Locale.preferredLanguages
Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations
Bundle.main.localizations
```

all of them are returning "en" only in IntentExtensionTarget.

here is an example where I am using the code:

```
extension IntentHandler: ReciterAndSurahIntentHandling {
    
    func provideSurahOptionsCollection(for intent: ReciterAndSurahIntent, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<NSString>?, Error?) -> Void) {
        
        Locale.preferredLanguages
        Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations
        Bundle.main.localizations
        // All of them return "en" only, and I have multiple localization for the app.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You get EN only, because localization in description and widget names is based on device language. If you would try to set device language to a different one, localization should work. As for now, it is not possible to use in-app language on widget description and name localization.

Comment: That is unfortunate, do you have any workarounds for this?

Comment: I don't think there is a workaround for now. I was doing a widget a month ago, had the same issue and unfortunately, I was not able to find anything about it. Hope in future they will release something :)

Comment: @Jkrist There are any official statement for that ?

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple solution:

1. Add AppGroups capability for both Parent App and the widget.
2. Create simple `UserDefaults`

   ```
    let SharedGroupName = "group.pl.blueworld.fieldservice"
    let PreferredLanguageKey = "PreferredLanguageKey"
    extension UserDefaults {
        static let shared = UserDefaults(suiteName: SharedGroupName)!
    }
   ```
3. Save current language in shared `UserDefaults`.

   ```
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        UserDefaults.shared.setValue(Locale.preferredLanguages[0].prefix(2), forKey: PreferredLanguageKey)
    }
   ```
4. Access value inside Widget View:

   ```
    struct MyView: View {
        var language: String {
            return UserDefaults.shared.string(forKey: PreferredLanguageKey) ?? "en"
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: This has a downside, if the app wan't opened, the language won't get updated.

Comment: A widget cannot be added without the app at least being opened once cfr Apple docs

Comment: I would recommend to do the step 3 both for sceneDidBecomeActive AND sceneWillEnterForeground