# App widget description and name localization

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios14, widgetkit

I would like to know if it is possible to use the app language on localization, and not the phone language?

I am talking about:

```
.configurationDisplayName("widget.name".localized())
```

and

```
.description("widget.description".localized())
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977816/how-to-force-an-ios-app-to-use-a-certain-localization

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can provide localised strings to both `configurationDisplayName` and `description` as they also accept `LocalizedStringKey` parameters:

```
/// Sets the localized name shown for a widget when a user adds or edits
/// the widget.
///
/// - Parameter displayName: The key for the localized name to display.
/// - Returns: A widget configuration that includes a descriptive name for
///   the widget.
public func configurationDisplayName(_ displayNameKey: LocalizedStringKey) -> some WidgetConfiguration
```

```
/// Sets the localized description shown for a widget when a user adds or
/// edits the widget.
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - descriptionKey: The key for the localized description to display.
/// - Returns: A widget configuration with a description of the widget.
public func description(_ descriptionKey: LocalizedStringKey) -> some WidgetConfiguration
```

For more information see:

- [Localization in SwiftUI](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2019/10/16/localization-in-swiftui/)
- [How to implement localization in Swift UI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58578341/8697793)

Comment: I am talking about description and name. When using these, localized are being done on the device language, and I would need to use the app language. I mean that it works - localization works but localizes based on device, not the app language :)

Comment: Oh, I understand now - I don't think we have this possibility yet. You can inject locale to the view environment but it's not possible for Widgets. Similar thread is here: [Localize iOS 14 dynamic widget configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64175497/8697793)

Answer (score 1):

1. you can get the correct translation you want after initializing the language settings.

```
var disName: String {
    LoadLocalizeSettings()
    return "disName.key".localize()
}
```

2. perform like this:
   `.configurationDisplayName(disName)`
3. If it doesn't work? you also can pod 'Localize'

```
func LoadLocalizeSettings() {
        Localize.shared.update(provider: .strings)
        Localize.shared.update(bundle: bundle)
        Localize.shared.update(fileName: filename)
        if let language = youWantThis {
            update(language)
        }
        else {
            update(.english)
        }

}
```