# Selected app language ignored in widgets but works in app

Tags: ios, localization, widget

I'm building a Swift + SwiftUI app with a few widgets. I'm localizing it in two languages (en, it), and if I go in the iOS settings, under my app, and change language to Italian, I correctly see the app using the italian localization.

For some reason though the widgets are always using the english localization. I'm using a mix of `Text()` and `NSLocalizedString` in my widgets.

The localization files have 100% completion on both languages. The iPhone language is set to: English, Italian (in this order)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it is still not possible to use in-app language on widgets. It only uses device language(shame on Apple). But as in the link below you can use this solution but be aware of the downside.

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65763528/20472014)

Comment: In the future, instead of posting a link to another answer, you should flag the question as a duplicate.